# The client side listeners of the Apache mina FtpServer

Tags: java, ftp, automation, apache-mina

Trying to implement a FTP server/client using the mina framework. Now the server side of it all is very easy and very well explained. How to make it a standalone windows service and what not.

But I'm having a very hard time discovering information about the client whether it would suit my needs or not. What I need, is for the client to check whether a file appears on the ftp directory in a certain folder, if it does, download it. After download finished, do something with the file. At the same time the client will also have to upload a file. All automatically. now I was thinking of making a java application with threads running. One thread for the uploading when conditions were met while another thread for the checking if file was available. So periodically check if a file was available, and if so download it. I would however like it, if there were another way? Without having to 'poll' every other minute or so? Is it possible or am I just wishful thinking?

Also, I have looked around to how to exactly implement the client and am having a bit trouble finding documentation about it and placing it a bit as well. From what I have gathered, now don't shoot if it's wrong, but the client will be a standard Java application having access to the functionalities using the jars and what not of the framework right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of Apache Mina having an FTP client. The Apache project already has an FTP client in the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library.

As for your approach, it seems like it will work just fine. The alternative would be for your client application to have a callback mechanism that the **server** could call when it detects that a new file appears. I'd recommend you do the polling first, and if you see that it's a problem then try the callback approach.

Comment: Hey hiro thanks, yeah you were right, apache mina does not have an FTP client, a misreading on my part. When I read: "Yes. You can create both client and server applications with MINA. Please take a look at IoConnector and IoAcceptor." on the apache mina FAQ I hadn't realised it wasn't about the FTP project. But thanks for the info.